# Reduce count so that it shows a count for all suppliers per user

Tags: javascript, node.js, count, reduce

I have this object called `grouped`:

```
{ '1':
   [ { id: 1,
       name: 'John Doe',
       supplierName: 'Sup1',
       count: '21' } ],
  '2':
   [ { id: 2,
       name: 'Jane Doe',
       supplierName: 'Sup1',
       count: '95' } ],
  '3':
   [ { id: 3,
       name: 'Paul',
       supplierName: 'Sup1',
       count: '2' },
     { id: 3,
       name: 'Paul',
       supplierName: 'Sup2',
       count: '1' } 
    ] 
}
```

I create a users object with this:

```
    let users = _.map(grouped, userArray => ({
      id: userArray[0].id,
      name: userArray[0].name,
      suppliers: _.reduce(userArray, (accumulated, supplierObj) => {
        if (supplierObj.supplierName) {
          accumulated.push({
            title: supplierObj.supplierName,
          });
        }
        return accumulated;
      }, []),
    }));
```

It currently looks like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "suppliers": [
                {
                    "title": "Sup1"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "suppliers": [
                {
                    "title": "Sup1"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Paul",
            "suppliers": [
                {
                    "title": "Sup1"
                },{
                    "title": "Sup2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I now want to add `count` in a way that my output is like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "count": "21",
            "suppliers": [
                {
                    "title": "Sup1"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "count": "95",
            "suppliers": [
                {
                    "title": "Sup1"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Paul",
            "count": "2",
            "suppliers": [
                {
                    "title": "Sup1"
                },{
                    "title": "Sup2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I simply add `count: userArray[0].count`, my output is correct for every user who has a single supplier but only picks the 1st for any with more than one. E.g. For the above, Paul would show a count of 2 and for Paul, there are 2 customers for Sup1 and 1 for Sup2. How do I fix this so users like Paul who have more than one supplier?

Comment: Your desired output is like the last json with count 3?

Comment: Sorry. Head is fried. Edited now.

Comment: Wait. Why? Whats the expected count for Paul and why?

Comment: The last object is the expected output has `count:2`. That is confusing. Do you want the `count`  of last element of input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  count: userArray.reduce((sum, user) => sum + +user.count, 0)
```

Using `.reduce` you can sum up the counts. The unary plus is needed to cast the strings into numbers.

And you don't need lodash, and you don't need to reduce if you can filter and map:

```
  const users = Object.values(grouped).map(users => ({
     id: users[0].id,
     name: users[0].name,
     suppliers: users.map(user => user.supplierName).filter(it => it),
     count: users.reduce((sum, user) => sum + +user.count, 0),
  }));
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I was trying a reduce function but had it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `map()`. And use `reduce()` to get `count`

```js
let obj = { '1': [ { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', supplierName: 'Sup1', count: '21' } ], '2': [ { id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', supplierName: 'Sup1', count: '95' } ], '3': [ { id: 3, name: 'Paul', supplierName: 'Sup1', count: '2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Paul', supplierName: 'Sup2', count: '1' } ] }

const res = Object.values(obj).map((x) => (
  { 
    id:x[0].id,
    name:x[0].name,
    suppliers:x.map(title => ({title})),
    count:x.reduce((ac,a) => +ac + +a.count, 0)
  }
))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I just saw it on another post.  Someone appears to be just downvoting everything.

Answer (score -1):

You can use map() and length()

```
users.map(user => ({
...user,
count: user.suppliers.length()
}))
```